# Can I get the AI to only flee and not attack?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Trying to get the "Study Harder" title for Genis, on the Golem, with Stone Blast.

Unfortunately, it's not tough enough to survive against my party going all out, so he can't get the requisite 10 uses...

**Is it possible to get people to just run?** If I could do that for everyone except Genis, he'd get the Title easy.

But it seems there's no AI settings to do that?

"Hold Position" gets people to stay in place and not attack, leaving them very vulnerable... But every other Position strat gets them to attack?

And there's no Action strat to stop them from attacking at all?

Answer (score 1):

To get *Study Harder!* you need to "use elemental spells the targeted enemy has resistance to at least 10 times in one battle", so you may have different solutions changing spell or enemy.

I found a strategy on [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/561316-tales-of-symphonia/55116415):

> I got mine by using **Eruption on the Dragon in the Earth Temple**. It's the only enemy that lasts long enough to get in multiple spells. I also had Raine healing, Zelos (me, with Eruption as a shortcut) making sure the Dragon didn't get too close to my mages, and Lloyd with most of his strong techs turned off so he didn't kill it too fast.

Comment: Oh! Right! I can turn everyone else's techs off! Forgot that! ... Golem seems to be the earliest it can be done, so I'm trying for that! Otherwise, yes, others are easier.

Comment: @Malady whatever strategy you prefer, good luck :)