# Does Stone Blast deal Earth damage, and are Golems strong against it? ... Trying to get "Study Harder" at the earliest possible opportunity

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Trying to get Genis's *Study Harder!* title, where I need to "use elemental spells the targeted enemy has resistance to at least 10 times in one battle"...

And I'm sure I had him fire off 10~11 Stone Blasts (Emptying out the TP bar, at 74 TP, 7 TP a shot) on a Martel Temple Golem, which, when Lensed, had a mountain-y symbol with a minus sign to the left of it.

Which, and intuition would agree with, the idea that *that* means "Earth Attacks are a Bad Idea against this enemy"...

A.k.a, *resistance*. ... So, either my intuition's off... Or just looking at the title description now...

Where I said "I", and [Pickerman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/390053/108916) said "you"... Do ***I*** have to semi-auto / manually control Genis for the title, instead of letting the AI do all the work? ... And no, that's not it. I did 11 manual attacks once. Still didn't get it.

**Does Stone Blast deal Earth damage, and are Golems strong against it?**

Comment: I'm curious, did you finally achieved that?

Comment: @pinckerman - Nope, trying to get out of Triet and only let the AI do the fighting! Botta's Earth attacks are real annoying! Ground up to LV13... Ah well. I knew what I was getting into.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, did you get it finally?

Comment: @pinckerman - I'm just assuming it'll work, it's pretty well researched!

Comment: I swear, I'm gonna play this game in the future just to get that title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Aselia wikia](https://aselia.fandom.com/wiki/Stone_Blast):

> Stone Blast is a classic **Earth-elemental** spell in the Tales series, commonly appearing in the novice tier of damage.

And also from [monster list](https://aselia.fandom.com/wiki/ToS_-_Monster_List):
[image]

So you are doing it right, apparently.

See [this video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Nn-pcG5UeA), and try to apply the same strategy with your golem. In the first battle there are 2 fire element enemies with Genis casting 10 Fire balls. The player keeps track with the usage counter on the lower-right side of the menu. At 2.31 Genis is rewarded with "Study Harder!" title.

**EDIT:**

According to [TalesReserve forum](https://talesreserve.forumotion.net/t342-problems-with-some-genis-in-battle-titles), there are 3 different types of *resistance*:

> **Reduce** (half damage): Lesser damage and the damage numbers tend to be slightly smaller.
> **Invalid** (no damage): The attack does not produce any damage numbers at all and the enemy does not stagger.
> **Absorb** (regains health): The damage numbers are green because the enemy restores HP instead of losing it.

Since you're trying only with the first one, maybe the simply *reducted* halving damage is not considered towards "has resistance to".

And also, from [Playstation Trophies](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/223310-complete-titles-list/):

> Genis must say something about the spells **not being effective** for it to count.

And this sounds more restrictive that just "has resistance to" stated elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at the video... Genis's Fire Balls against the Fire Elements, deal Green-type damage, a.k.a, it's actually healing the Elements? Is *that* what I need? ... Because Golems still take regular White-type damage from Stone Blast...

Comment: Yeah, I mean, did the translation not get as precise as it actually requires? With the spells actually needing to be absorbed, not just resisted?

Comment: @Malady I've edit my answer. You may be right, there are different types of "resistance". The video I linked proves that "absorb" works, from your testing it appears that the simple resistant does not. You may be luckier with the "invalid" one. Does Genis say something when you cast Stone Blast on Golems?

Comment: Just "Get 'em! Stone Blast!"

Comment: @Malady mmh, that doesn't sound negative like the "what the heck!" heard in the video...

Comment: Yep. Pretty solid conclusions we have here. I'll give you the checkmark in a few days. ... Or earlier since there's not much to add... ... Now I either find something that Absorbs before Exbelua... Wiki confirmed who I thought it was... ..., or leave the Title 'til later... And grind Golems for Yellow Quartz because why not.

Comment: @Malady no rush, I'm glad to help until you'll get it, eventually. The requirements are utterly misleading.

Comment: Well, if you wanna check my work... It seems that I can't get it this early, since Zombies might Resist Dark to the needed extent... But that's not a solution since Genis doesn't *ever* learn any Dark spells...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128915/discussion-between-pinckerman-and-malady).

Comment: Hm... I only used it 5 times, once, and it got me the Title... vs. Fire Elementals... So, each "use" seems to count whenever it hits a different enemy...